# VLC Mosaic effect: Use existing movie source as background with Video Lan Manager / VLM

Tags: video, vlc, video-processing, quicktime, effect

How can I use an existing movie source as a background in VLC using VLM Video Lan Manager?

My current VLM code looks like this:

```
new isight broadcast
setup isight input qtcapture://
setup isight output #mosaic-bridge{chroma=YUVA,vfilter=alphamask{mask=../mask.png},width=320,height=240}
setup isight enabled

new background broadcast enabled
setup background input fake://
setup background option fake-file=/Users/imac/Desktop/bg.png
setup background option fake-aspect-ratio="4:3"
setup background option mosaic-width=400
setup background option mosaic-height=300
setup background option mosaic-keep-picture
setup background option mosaic-rows=1
setup background option mosaic-cols=1
setup background option mosaic-position=1 
setup background option mosaic-order=1,1,1,1
setup background output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=mp4v,vb=10000,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=512}:bridge-in{delay=400,id-offset=100}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=test.mp4}

control isight play
control background play
```

Comment: Why are you doing it with VLM? Have you seen this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiB1t4x_uKM).

Comment: not available in germany (umg)   you need a vlm for scripting with vlc

Comment: did this setup work with qtcapture for you? i can't seem to get qtcapture to work with mosaic...

Comment: well I did not try it with qtcapture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag that you are looking for is `--video-wallpaper`

Add this to your VLM:

`setup background option video-wallpaper=1`